# jQuery console says gmap function does not exist? Is this the addition of jQuery script files?

Tags: jquery, google-maps

The following is a simple rendition of a map, testing the addition of the Google maps jQuery v.3:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Google Maps JQuery Plugin Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery /1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="PATH_TO_PLUGIN/jquery.ui.map.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#map_canvas').gmap({
            'some_option': 'some_value'
        }); // Add the contructor
        // addMarker returns a jQuery wrapped google.maps.Marker object 
        var $marker = $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', {
            'position': '57.7973333,12.0502107',
            'bounds': true
        });
        $marker.click(function () {
            $('#map_canvas').gmap('openInfoWindow', {
                'content': 'Hello World!'
            }, this);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:250px;height:250px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to make sure that the following library is loaded correctly :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="PATH_TO_PLUGIN/jquery.ui.map.js"></script>
```

as this contains the `.gmap()` function - so if the library is not correctly loaded you will receive that exact error message (ie `gmap function does not exist`) ...

Secondly - you are trying to access the DOM before its fully loaded - your code in the `<head>` tag will be executed before the `<div>` is actually loaded.

So you should do this :

```
$(function() {
    $('#map_canvas').gmap({
        'some_option': 'some_value'
    }); // Add the contructor
    // addMarker returns a jQuery wrapped google.maps.Marker object 
    var $marker = $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', {
        'position': '57.7973333,12.0502107',
        'bounds': true
    });
    $marker.click(function() {
        $('#map_canvas').gmap('openInfoWindow', {
            'content': 'Hello World!'
        }, this);
    });
});
```

Wrapping your code within the `$(function() {` block will ensure its only executed when the DOM is ready - [see the docs for `ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/X5r8r/451/)